# Yii2 DataGrid different buttons set for the first and last row

Tags: php, datagrid, yii2

I need to reorder rows in DataGrid, so I've added two buttons for each row 'Up' and 'Down':

```
        <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'columns' => [
            [
                'headerOptions' => ['style' => 'width:56px'],
                'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
                'template' => '{Up} {Down}',
                'buttons' => [
                    'Up' => function($url, $model, $key) {
                        return Html::a('',['/admin/content/up', 'id' => $key], ['class' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up']);
                    },
                    'Down' => function($url, $model, $key) {
                        return Html::a('',['/admin/content/down', 'id' => $key], ['class' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down']);
                    },
                ]
            ],
            'content'
        ]
    ]);
    ?>
```

There's no pagination, all data fit one page. Now it looks like:

[image: Current look]

And i want to make it look more neat like this:

[image: What I want look]

So I need to hide 'Up' and 'Down' button for the first and last row respectively. Can't get how to make it or even how to get row number from anonymous button function.

Comment: ActionColumn has property "visibleButtons" and in callback function  `function ($model, $key, $index)` $index is row number

Comment: you an try this
`$count = $dataProvider->getTotalCount()`
after that add this attribute in your action column
`'visibleButtons' => [
                            'Up' => function ($model, $key, $index) {
                                return $index == 0 ? false : true;
                            }, 'Down' => function ($model, $key, $index) use ($count) {
                                return $index == ($count - 1) ? false : true;
                            }]`

Comment: Thanks, it works!

Comment: @NimishaMolia You should provide a normal answer instead of putting a solution into the comments. Helpful to others and you get some reputation.

Comment: @robsch, sure, next time i will do it

Comment: @NimishaMolia You can still do it. Question is not closed if you thought that. I don's see a reason not to do it...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$count = $dataProvider->getTotalCount();
```

after that add this attribute in your action column

```
'visibleButtons' => [
    'Up' => function ($model, $key, $index) {
         return $index == 0 ? false : true; 
     }, 
    'Down' => function ($model, $key, $index) use ($count) { 
         return $index == ($count - 1) ? false : true; 
     }
]
```

Comment: I like your solution. Also you can create functions in model isItFirst and isItLast. Check that and show or hide it depends on result.